# Automating install of Docker and image pull using python or bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, docker, automation

I am trying to automate the process of installing the docker-engine and then  asking the user if he would like to pull rhel/suse/centos images.

Using python was my first idea but I have added bash script to make things easier, python seemed not too friendly to run cli commands.

Now, I am planning to expand the functionality and shell script will not scale.
How do I convert this script to python? Many common command line operations such as "yum install",etc are not easy without using additional python imports.

If you have any easier suggestions, please advice

Thanks!

This is bash script still in the works...

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

echo
echo " - Installing packages"
echo

if [[ -e /usr/bin/yum ]]; then
    #Verify packages are up to date
    yum update
    #Install Docker
    yum install docker-engine
else
    echo "No yum, lets try apt-get"
    sudo apt-get update
    #sudo apt-get -y upgrade
    #sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-`uname -r`
    #sudo apt-get install docker-engine
fi

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo success
else
  echo failed
  exit
fi

#start Docker
echo "Would you like to start Docker and pull Images? Select 1 or 2"
select y1 in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $y1 in
        Yes ) service docker start; docker pull "rhel:7.2" ;docker pull "mstormo/suse" ;break;;
        No ) exit;;
    esac



echo " - Complete!"
echo

done
```

Comment: If you want to automatically setup multiple machines, you maybe want to use tools like Puppet https://github.com/garethr/garethr-docker or Chef https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/docker

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I was able to use subprocess and get things working in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I was able to make it work in Python. I will leave the code here, in case anyone needs it.

Cheers!
Rohit

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

uid = Popen(['id', '-u'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
uid_get = uid.stdout.read(1)
if uid_get !=  '0':
    print "This script needs to be run as root"

print " - Installing packages "

check1 = Popen(['/usr/bin/yum'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
check_yum = check1.stdout.read()
if check_yum == ' ':
    print "Yum is not found, trying apt-get"
    proc = Popen('apt-get update', shell=True, stdin=None, executable="/bin/bash")
    proc.wait()
    proc = Popen('apt-get upgrade', shell=True, stdin=None, executable="/bin/bash")
    proc.wait()
    proc = Popen('apt-get install', shell=True, stdin=None, executable="/bin/bash")
    proc.wait()
    proc = Popen('apt-get install docker-engine', shell=True, stdin=None, executable="/bin/bash")
    proc.wait()
else:
    print "Running yum install"
    proc = Popen('yum update', shell=True, stdin=None, executable="/bin/bash")
    proc.wait()
    proc = Popen('yum install docker-engine', shell=True, stdin=None, executable="/bin/bash")
    proc.wait()

print "Would you like to start Docker and pull images - RHEL and SUSE? -> y or n ?"
y="yes"
n="no"
choice = raw_input().lower()
if choice in y:
    print "Pulling RHEL and SUSE images"
    proc = Popen('service docker start; docker pull "rhel:7.2" ;docker pull "mstormo/suse" ; docker run rhel sh -c "cat /etc/*release"; docker run "mstormo/suse" sh -c "cat /etc/*release"', shell=True, stdin=None, executable="/bin/bash")
        proc.wait()
elif choice in n:
    print "Thank you, exiting...."
else:
print " Invalid selection"


print " - Complete! "
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the sh module:

```
from sh import docker
for line in docker('build', '-t', some_tag, '.', _iter=True):
    sys.stdout.write(str(line))
```

This is a long running command so it is nice to show its output
line by line.  This is what the `for loop` and `_iter` does.